# Magento 2.1 : How to overwrite default page layout in Block

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, configuration, page

I have a custom module having layout XML file for the front end, in which the default page layout configuration is set to **one column**, I wish to give the user the ability to change the configuration as specified in the system configurations(like 2columns-left, 2columns-right, 3coulmns). I can get the values from configuration via helper in to the block file prepareLayout ,I would like to know if we can  set the layout just like the pagetitle , metakeyowords we use to set. 
How can we set and overwrite default values in prepare layout in block file? Thanks.

> The XML default value is :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Comment: So you need to dynemically set page layout which is selected from admin?

Comment: yes , the user will choose his desire layout from the module configurations-which are similar to the magento default.

Comment: I post the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set page layout from the controller action. Suppose this is your action file avilable at this location.

```
app/code/Vendor/Extension/Controller/Youraction/Action.php
```

Put this code like this.

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Youraction;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Action extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, ['isIsolated' => true]); 

        // YOUR LOGIC TO GET SELECTED LAYOUT FROM ADMIN 
        $youradminlayout = 'XYZ'; 
        $page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($youradminlayout);
        return $page;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncought Error call to undefined method ::setPageLayout()

Comment: Can you show the code which you have try.

Comment: I update my answer, please check now.

Comment: ok , I will get back soon

Comment: Ok, If above code help you, please accept it, so it will help other in community as well.

Comment: your code shows blank , you need to replace $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE); with $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, ['isIsolated' => true]);

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Now it help you then please accept it, so it will help other in community as well.